# While doing terraform upgrade to the latest version, should we also do terraform.lock.hcl?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I am doing terraform upgrade and in one of the module the terraform hcl lock file also get committed to the repo I need to know if I need to upgrade the file as well and commit it to repository(source code)

I have already done upgrade to the module and ran terrfaorm plan which is working fine.

Comment: The `.terraform.lock.hcl` file is for provider versions, not terraform.

Comment: @Marko E Sure thing, would it be bad practice that I leave it as is in source code ?

Comment: Nope, it is actually suggested you commit it to the version control system so everyone gets the same developer experience. It is very similar to what you can see with NodeJS, e.g., the `package-lock.json` file. However, take note that you have to make sure the provider lock file does not break experience in a mixed environment (e.g., Windows, MacOS, Linux), because binary files (i.e., providers) are different for different CPU architecture.

Comment: @Marko E So is it upto me if I update the file with the recent sha(latest terraform version) or not ?

Comment: This is not related to terraform version, rather the version of the provider you use in your code. Examples are AWS, Azure, GCP, etc.

Comment: Also, for newer versions of terraform, the file gets updated automatically when you run `terraform init`.

Comment: @MarkoE Providers I haven't changed, so it will be irrelevant if I do any change to terraform.lock.hcl file in source code?

Comment: Ok, so if you do `git status` are any changes shown for the `.terraform.lock.hcl` file or not?

Comment: @MArko E this question was an eye opener, as checked git status doesn't show any change in the lock.hcl file. It was just a colleague questioning me if I should update the file or not to the source code. The answer is not required. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

See https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/files/dependency-lock which says the `terraform.lock.hcl` file is for tracking provider dependencies.

You can review the changes to this file and decide whether you want to keep (commit) these changes.